# django test client gets 404 for all urls

Tags: django, django-testing

I am doing my first experiments with django testing and I am having the problem that I always get the 404 template regardless which url (even /) I am using.
If I throw the very same code into the django shell it's working as expected and always presents me the contents of the requested url.

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('test', 'test', 'test')
        self.user.is_staff = True 
        self.user.save()
        self.client = Client()

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username='test', password= 'test'))
        self.client.get("/")
```

The login returns True, but the get() fails. Any hints what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that most views use something like `get_object_or_404`, `get_list_or_404`, or simply raise `Http404` when there's a problem accessing some object or another. You'll need to make sure that your test database is populated with sufficient objects to fulfill all these requirements to make the view not return a 404.

*Remember, when running tests, the database is rolled back after each test (using transactions)*, so each test method must stand on its own or the `setUp` method must populate the database with any required dependencies.